# iOS3, iOS4, xibbed UIViewController and displaying data

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, xib

I'm writing an app that will run on iOS3.0 and up.

The app has a custom `UIViewController` (say), which I'm instantiating from a .xib file. It's view comprises a single `UILabel`, which I've correctly declared and synthesized etc. in my custom `UIViewController` header and implementation files.

I'd like to set the text of this `UILabel` dynamically, and for it to be shown to the user by the time my `UIViewController` appears. For sake of argument please assume the text setting method is expensive.

The catch is on iOS3.0 with my `UIViewController` at least, `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *) aNibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *) aNibBundleOrNil` returns before `-(void)viewDidLoad` does, but on my iOS4.0 device it's the other way around. The text label can therefore be `nil` when I don't want it to be.

Thus, I don't know where I can set the text in such a way as to keep both iOS3.0 and iOS4.0 happy.

Any advice here?

Answer (score 4):

Can you please explain how your label comes out to be nil?

If you have taken an outlet for the label, then in either case, in the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method it cannot be nil, provided the label outlet is properly connected in the xib file.

If you have not taken the label outlet and doing it by code, then instantiate the label again in `- (void)viewDidLoad` method and set its text right over there and then add it to the view controller's view.

For more information - read the `- (void)viewDidLoad` and `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` method in the [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference

Comment: Hmm. It's probably because I have a lengthy script on a second thread for iOS4 but not yet iOS3. Developing separately for both is confusing.